# How to load a Custom TableViewCell in a TableView on Ipad?

Tags: ipad, uitableview, custom-cell

First, sorry for my english, I'm french :)

Like say in the title, I want to put a custom tableviewcell in a simple tableview on ipad. This is necessary because I want to generate a table with 5 labels.

I use a separate `UITableViewCell` Class with a NIB.

This is my code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    CustomTableCell *cell = (CustomTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];    

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableCell" owner:self options:nil]; 
        cell = customTableCell;
        self.customTableCell = nil;
    }   

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *rowLabelEcheance = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [contentsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [customTableCell.labelEcheance setText:rowLabelEcheance];

    NSString *rowLabelCapitalRestantDu = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", >>>>>>>  [contentsList2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [customTableCell.labelCapitalRestantDu setText:rowLabelCapitalRestantDu];

    NSString *rowLabelInterets = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [contentsList3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [customTableCell.labelInterets setText:rowLabelInterets];

    NSString *rowLabelAmortissement = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", >[contentsList4 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [customTableCell.labelAmortissement setText:rowLabelAmortissement];

    NSString *rowLabelMontant = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [contentsList5 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [customTableCell.labelMontant setText:rowLabelMontant];

    return cell;
}
```

Can you help me ? I spend 8 hours of work for this problem....

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else has this problem, you can download a working example project here: https://github.com/ijoshsmith/CustomCellDemo

Otherwise, here are the instructions:

There are a few ways of doing this that I know of.

Assuming the following names and file structure

```
-UITableCellCustomClass.h
-UITableCellCustomClass.m
-UITableCellCustomClass.xib
-UITableViewClass.h 
-UITableViewCustomClass.m
-UITableViewCustomClass.xib
```

With Interface Builder, to create a custom table cell you need to do this:

1.) Create a custom table cell from a NIB (as you have done) which inherits from UITableViewCell

2.) Unhook the "File's Owner" in IB for your custom table cell class and point it at the table class which you are wanting the cell to appear in e.g. change it to UITableViewCustomClass.

3.) Click the table cell in your IB screen and go to the field that says UITableViewCell and change it to inherit from your custom table cell class e.g. UITableCellCustomClass

4.) MAke sure you have created all the fields and properties as well as outlets for your textfields and made the necessary connections in interfacebuilder between your table cell class and the cell in your custom cell xib (note: NOT the file's owner...)

5.) I see you have the "cell identifier" variable there...but just in case you haven't yet, make sure that in your CustomTableCell xib you have changed the cell identifier field to match your custom identifier.

That should do it I believe if my memory serves correctly. It looks like you are doing the rest right with your table and setting the properties on the cell.

I believe that is all of it. I have it written down in explicit detail someplace because it is such a pain.

UPDATE:

IF you have five labels, you may need to alter the vertical height of the table rows so that all the labels will show (unless you have a really wide table).

Make sure the table has both it's delegate and data source pointed at it's parent class (the one hosting the cell loading logic)

You must override this function:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        return YOURCUSTOMROWHEIGHT;
}
```

UPDATE: Apparently the above was not sufficient so I'll try again:

Try doing this using the following UINib Method:

Add this to your UICustomTableView.h class

```
UINib *cellLoader;
```

Next, try the following (assuming you followed all the steps above)...maybe a UINib loader will help? I am pretty sure I covered all the proper steps after looking over my notes. One thing to try is to create a class that extends UIViewController, then delete the view from that, add your table cell and do teh steps above and change the base class to inherit from UITableCellView.

```
static NSString *CellClassName = @"YourCellClassName";

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) 
    {
        cellLoader = [[UINib nibWithNibName:CellClassName bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] retain];
    }
    return self;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Make sure your identifier is set properly in IB
    CustomCellClass *cell = (CustomCellClass *)[tableView     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellClassName];
    if (!cell)
    {
        NSArray *topLevelItems = [cellLoader instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelItems objectAtIndex:0];
    }
     /* set your cell properties here */



    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I've done all the points thats you say. Console say : "2011-08-10 09:35:06.508 EmpruntClassiqueV10[43282:207] -[SecondViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b66700"...

Comment: It's for ipad, i have the space to put 5 labels in one line. I place them in IB on my custom cell nib.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple piece of code:

```
...
if(cell == nil){
   NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCellView" owner:self options:nil];
   cell = (MyCellView *) [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
...
```